# C# - Large number to number with unit (10000 to 10K)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm making a clicker game and I got it working but my code is very repetitive.
I want it to be less repetitive but I don't really know how to do that.
This is what I currently have, you'll notice its not very clean, all I want to do is simplify the void Update part.
Cause with the way I'm doing it now I'm giving myself a lot of work and unnecessary code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public long coins; // Coin value
    private double currentCoins; // Coin value above 10000 in Unit
    private long addition; // Addition per click
    public int upgradeLevel; // Upgrades bought
    private int multiplier; // Multiplier based on upgrades bought
    public GameObject coinText;
    public GameObject coinUnit;

    void Start ()
    {
        coins = 0; // Start capital
        upgradeLevel = 1; // Start level
        multiplier = 2; // First multiplier (active when upgrade level 25 |>)
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        if (coins.ToString().Length < 4)
        {
            coinUnit.GetComponent<Text>().text = "";
            coinText.GetComponent<Text>().text = coins.ToString();
        } else {
            if (coins.ToString().Length < 7)
            {
                currentCoins = coins;
                coinUnit.GetComponent<Text>().text = "K";
                currentCoins = currentCoins / 1000;
                coinText.GetComponent<Text>().text = Math.Round(currentCoins, 2).ToString();
            } else {
                if (coins.ToString().Length < 10)
                {
                    currentCoins = coins;
                    coinUnit.GetComponent<Text>().text = "M";
                    currentCoins = currentCoins / 1000000;
                    coinText.GetComponent<Text>().text = Math.Round(currentCoins, 2).ToString();
                } else {
                    if (coins.ToString().Length < 13)
                    {
                        currentCoins = coins;
                        coinUnit.GetComponent<Text>().text = "B";
                        currentCoins = currentCoins / 1000000000;
                        coinText.GetComponent<Text>().text = Math.Round(currentCoins, 2).ToString();
                    } else {
                        currentCoins = coins;
                        coinUnit.GetComponent<Text>().text = "T";
                        currentCoins = currentCoins / 1000000000000;
                        coinText.GetComponent<Text>().text = Math.Round(currentCoins, 2).ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnClick()
    {
        if (upgradeLevel < 25)
        {
            addition = 1 * upgradeLevel;
            coins = coins + addition;
        } else {
            multiplier = 2 * (upgradeLevel / 25);
            addition = (1 * upgradeLevel) * multiplier;
            coins = coins + addition;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT: would it be possible to assign a value such as K based on how many times 1000 fits in coins (coins = 1000; coins / 1000 = 1, so it would put K)

Comment: If your code works fine, may I suggest https://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Did i post it in the wrong place?

Answer (score 1):

This is a little cleaner.

```
var coinDescription = new CoinDescriptor(coins);
coinUnit.GetComponent<Text>().text = coinDescription.Label;
coinText.GetComponent<Text>().text = coinDescription.CoinText;
...
public class CoinDescriptor { 
    public CoinDescriptor(long  coinCount)
    {
        TotalCoinCount = coinCount;
        decimal convertedCoinCount;
        if (coinCount < 1000) {
            Label ="";
            convertedCoinCount = TotalCoinCount;
        }
        else if (coinCount < 1000000000)
        {
            Label = "M";
            convertedCoinCount = Math.Round(TotalCoinCount / 1000M, 2);
        }
        else if (coinCount < 1000000000000)
        {
            Label = "B";
            convertedCoinCount = Math.Round(TotalCoinCount / 1000000000M, 2);
        }
        else
        {
            Label = "T";
            convertedCoinCount = Math.Round(TotalCoinCount / 1000000000000M, 2);
        }
        CoinText = String.Format("{0:n0}", convertedCoinCount);
    }
    public long TotalCoinCount { get; }
    public string Label { get; }
    public string CoinText { get; }
}
```

Comment: This is already cleaner but not really worth changing too, I want to be able to add more amounts but I don't want to use recurring code. For instance coins / 1000 if coins is 1000, it will assign K because 1000 fits once in 1000 and so on. Is this possible?

Comment: I'd recommend using optional number separator `_` : `1_000`, `1_000_000`. `1_000_000_000`

Comment: How would I be able to implement this into my code @Pac0

Comment: @MDauwe, sorry, the comment was on the code of this answer, not as an answer to your comment. I agree with your comment above, there is some "cleaner way", though I don't agree it's not woth changing your code. You can improve your code step by step.

Answer (score 0):

This is an adaptation from [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64538222/479251).

Then I tried to use something more absstract, you can just edit the list of suffixes, and will act accordingly, by step of thousand factor.

[Test it on rextester](https://rextester.com/VKX23961)

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var coinDescriptor = new CoinDescriptor();
            
            coinDescriptor.TotalCoins = 42;
            
            for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++)
            {
                coinDescriptor.TotalCoins *= 10;
                Console.WriteLine(coinDescriptor.DisplayText);
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    public class CoinDescriptor
    {
        private static readonly string[] suffixes = new string[] { "", "k", "M", "G", "T" };
        
        private long totalCoins;
        public long TotalCoins 
        { 
            get => totalCoins;
            set 
            { 
                totalCoins = value;
                UpdateDisplayText();
            }
        }
        
        public string DisplayText { get; private set; }  
        
        private void UpdateDisplayText()
        {
            int numberOfThousandExponent = (int) Math.Min(suffixes.Length - 1, Math.Floor(Math.Log10(totalCoins) / 3));
            string suffix = suffixes[numberOfThousandExponent];
            decimal valueDisplayed = (decimal) Math.Round(totalCoins / Math.Pow(1000d, numberOfThousandExponent), 2);
            DisplayText = valueDisplayed.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + suffix;
        }
    }
```

I didn't use a "Label" text field, just to show a different way to build the display text, but frankly I prefer William Edmondson's way in this matter.